# How to deal with "TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type str"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have an error regarding the python operations.
So what I want to do is to extract files in a folder that matches specific numbers from an Excel sheet. So my code is:

```
import os
import shutil
import pandas as pd

src_dir_path = r'D:\1. SEC EDGAR年报数据' 
to_dir_path = r'D:\12 年报提取尝试'  
df = pd.read_excel(r'D:\11. 年报提取尝试\CIK代码.xlsx')
ciklist = list(map(str, df['cik_full'].tolist()))
key1 = ciklist 

filelist = os.listdir(src_dir_path)  
for row in df:
    df.append(row)


def printallfiles(dirs, abspath):
    for file in dirs:
        sub_path = os.path.join(abspath, file)  
        if (os.path.isdir(sub_path)): 
            temppath = os.listdir(sub_path)
            printallfiles(temppath, sub_path)  
        else:
            if key1 in file:
                shutil.copy(sub_path, to_dir_path)


printallfiles(filelist, src_dir_path)
```

And my Traceback is:

```
D:\5Anaconda3\envs\py39\python.exe "D:/7PycharmPythonProjects/PythonLessons/File Extract Attempt 3.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\7PycharmPythonProjects\PythonLessons\File Extract Attempt 3.py", line 13, in <module>
    df.append(row)
  File "D:\5Anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 8965, in append
    concat(
  File "D:\5Anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\5Anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 294, in concat
    op = _Concatenator(
  File "D:\5Anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 384, in __init__
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

Process finished with exit code 1
```

And then when I run this code, it has the error "TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid". So I would like to know how to deal with this problem while still make this code running and end with actual results. Thank you all for help!

Comment: What does `for row in df:    df.append(row)` mean?

Comment: ah....this is the attempt that I tried to eliminate the error, but it doesn't work.....I'm new to python sorry....

Comment: your traceback is incomplete, can't help tou

Comment: Sorry, here's my traceback in the question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.